# WM 6.5 C# console application, capturing keystrokes while running in the background while another application has focus

Tags: c#, mobile, keystrokes

Hi I'm developing a C# WM 6.5 console application.  It is running in the background while another application has focus.  I need to be able to capture when the user presses the ESC key however I do not want to interfere with the operation of the main application.  I have no idea how to do this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a keylogger feature. You can check keylogging documents.

Comment: Sounds like there is no native/easy method, but with some Help of interop (say, "`PInvoke`") and this reply (C++ code!) combined with a learning process, it might point you into the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1047829/265165

Comment: do you know how to get and dispatch messages?

Comment: Turns out I can just use the following with WM 6.5:

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int keyCode);


if (GetAsyncKeyState(27) != 0)
{
    //do something here cause the ESC key was pressed
}

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your exact method

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll.dll")] 
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int keyCode); 
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(27) != 0) { //do something here cause the ESC key was pressed }
```